# Writeback between Excel 2007 and SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, ssis, excel-2007

What is the most efficient way of building a writeback between Excel 2007 and MS SQL Server 2008 R2?

I need a stable solution to communicate between Excel and SQL Server. I need to download data from a table in the database, calculate and fill in new data in Excel, and submit those new values to the database.

I found that SSIS should be able to do this, but it might be overkill if I miss out on a more standard way of connecting.

Comment: Is the calculated and new data based on user input?  If not it seems pointless to go to excel when you could do it all in SQL Server

Comment: The data is user-defined, and cannot be done with just logic in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I have used dynamic sql like so..

```
SET @sQl='SELECT ID=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY F2), * into xlCitems FROM '+dbo.fsExcelODS(@XLSPATH,'CITEMS')+' WHERE DESCRIPTION IS NOT NULL'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql;
```

the Scalar function dbo.fsexcelODS returns openDatasoure statement as is defined in

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fsExcelODS](@pathtods varchar(max),@sourceTable varchar(200))returns varchar(max)as 
begin

return  'OpenDataSource('+dbo.fsQuoteString('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0')+','+dbo.fsquoteString('Data Source='+dbo.fsdquotestring(@pathtods)+';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=10"')+')...'+@sourcetable


end
```